# instanceof returns false when created in Angular Library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

When created an object in an Angular Library, `instanceof` returns false.

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {genControl} from 'test-lib';                        // import a function from my own library.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const fcA = genControl();                               // Create a FormControl in Angular Library
    const fcB = new FormControl('');

    if (fcA instanceof FormControl) {
      console.log('fcA is instanceof FormControl');
    } else {
      console.log('fcA is not instanceof FormControl');     // displays this.
    }

    if (fcB instanceof FormControl) {
      console.log('fcB is instanceof FormControl');         // displays this.
    } else {
      console.log('fcB is not instanceof FormControl');
    }

  }
}
```

`test-lib` is an Angular Library project build as [this post](https://willtaylor.blog/complete-guide-to-angular-libraries/). The code for `genControl` is as below.

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

export function genControl(): FormControl {
  return new FormControl('');
}
```

The output of the code above is as follows.

```
fcA is not instanceof FormControl
fcB is instanceof FormControl
```

Why `fcA` is not an instance of `FormControl`? How should I fix for `fcA` will be instance of `FormControl`?

Angular version is same between main project `AppComponent` and Angular Library `genControl`, which is 9.1.11.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think I had similar: this could be correct if FormControls come from different places. Such as your lib is built - it's FormControl differs from FormControl that you are testing during execution. You could check it by debugging: during runtime check from where FormControls are comming - I am sure they comes from different files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @andriishupta mentioned, this is because the app and the lib imports `FormControl` from different files.
I should specify `paths` in `tsconfig.json` as follows.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
        :
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  },
```